# Правильный способ навигации по личному кабинету Laravel 8

Tags: html, css, ajax, laravel, frontend

Я изучаю Laravel 8 и у меня есть вопрос: у меня очень обычный личный кабинет. Большое меню сайта вверху, личное меню сбоку слева и контент посередине. В моем боковом меню есть несколько ссылок для навигации по личному кабинету. У меня есть макет с меню и футером, а также разные blade views для разных страниц.

Я уже пробовал .load ajax в jq:

```
$(document).on('click', "a.nav-item, .account-content a", function (event) {
    // Avoid the link click from loading a new page
    event.preventDefault();
    // Load the content from the link's href attribute
    $('.account-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    // Change link and page title
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", $(this).attr('href'));
    document.title = $(this).text();
});
```

На самом деле вначале это работает нормально, но затем я сталкиваюсь с другими проблемами. Например, я хочу иметь возможность вернуться назад по стрелкам браузера. Сейчас, возвращаясь к инструментам браузера, он меняет только ссылку, но ничего не загружает.

Как лучше всего перемещаться по этим страницам без перерисовки меню и нижнего колонтитула?